# How to teach linear programming and reductions?

Tags: programming, algorithms

Do you know any textbook with problems+solutions to support teaching of linear programming and reductions? In particular for: standard and slack forms, formulation of problems as linear programs, simplex method and algorithm, duality, etc.

Comment: This might be better on math educators: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/. I know of a great book, but it is old, and not accessible to beginners. Also, no code (old old old).

Comment: Why not just do problem solving using the GLPK? It coms with a MathProg compiler and a manual. You can introduce the concepts using a workshop approach.